# phonegap 2.7 android getpicture error callback always fired

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Everything is in the title, i'm accessing the camera via Camera.getPicture method, i can either choose a picture or take one but when i'm accessing either photo library or the camera to take a picture, my error callback is fired, so i can't get back the URI of the picture. It's not crashing my app i can still use it.
i've tried to use the "Foreground Camera plugin" for android, but the error callback is still fired everytime.

i get an error message : "07-09 18:33:55.728: D/CordovaLog(10038): error :Camera cancelled."

I'm testing my app with a Samsung Galaxy S2, however, when i test it with a Galaxy Tab 10, everything works fine, but i need to make it work on mobile devices.

i'm using Cordova 2.7.0 and AngularJS.

edit : Relevant error message :

```
07-09 18:47:47.183: D/DroidGap(11126): Paused the application!
07-09 18:47:47.183: D/CordovaWebView(11126): Handle the pause
07-09 18:47:47.183: D/DroidGap(11126): Incoming Result
07-09 18:47:47.183: D/DroidGap(11126): Request code = 18
07-09 18:47:47.183: D/DroidGap(11126): We have a callback to send this result to
07-09 18:47:47.183: D/DroidGap(11126): Resuming the App
07-09 18:47:47.203: D/DroidGap(11126): Paused the application!
07-09 18:47:47.203: D/CordovaWebView(11126): Handle the pause
07-09 18:47:47.213: W/CordovaPlugin(11126): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Camera169951334
07-09 18:47:47.213: W/CordovaPlugin(11126): Result was: "No result"
07-09 18:33:55.728: D/CordovaLog(10038): error :Camera cancelled
```

JavaScript :

```
  $scope.chooseImage = function() {
    navigator.notification.confirm('Ajoutez une photo', function (buttonIndex) {
     $scope.getImage(buttonIndex);
     },'PokeMe',["Prendre","Choisir"])
  };



$scope.getImage = function(buttonIndex) {
    var sourceType = buttonIndex == 1 ? Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA :        Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
    var options = {
      quality: 80,
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.BACK,
      correctOrientation: true
    }
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imgData) {
      window.safeApply($scope, function() {
        console.log('success'+imgData);
        $scope.profileSrc = imgData;
      });
    }, function (msg){console.log('error :'+msg)}, options); //This callback is fired
  };
}
```

HTML :

```
  <div ng-click="chooseImage()" style='margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 30px;' id="yellow_btn" ><p><img src='img/upload.png' />Ajoutez une photo</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to make sure the camera permissions for your app are there:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

If it's not there, then it probably works on your Galaxy Tab because older versions of Android were more permissive in their defaults for what applications could do, but your S2 has a newer version of Android and needs the explicit permissions to allow access to the camera.

**EDIT**: Based on this [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/8E5C6phqQA4), try changing the line:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

to

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in the `config.xml`

Comment: permissions i have in AndroidManifest.xml : android.permission.CAMERA,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: i think it solve my problem,my success callback is fired. But a new bug just occured, i use iScroll in my webview and the click event is always fired twice. Anyway thanks you for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was actually calling..
this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Oops, Error :()"));
while returning from **execute();**
as well as calling..
this.callbackContext.success(**your_data**);
remove first call from **execute();**.